# Spring DeferredResult only continue after result set or timeout

Tags: java, spring

I want to have my program wait for a value that gets set at a different point in my spring program. This value could be set from an entirely different API or an event handler for example.

Below is the controller that needs to wait for the result to be set and then used to do other things.

**Example.java**

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @Autowired
    RequestHolder requestHolder;
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {

        DeferredResult myRequest = new DeferredResult<>();
        requestHolder.addRequest(myRequest);
        //wait for myRequest to be handled somehow
        String myVar = (String) myRequest.getResult();
        /*
        myRequest should either have timed out or have a value by this point
        Do stuff with myVar
         */

        return "return something";
    }
}
```

**RequestHolder.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class RequestHolder {
    private List<DeferredResult> requestList;

    public RequestHolder(){
        this.requestList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addRequest(DeferredResult request){
        this.requestList.add(request);

    }

    public void clear(){
        this.requestList.clear();
    }

    public List<DeferredResult> getRequestList() {
        return requestList;
    }
}
```

**RequestHandler.java**

```
@RestController
public class RequestHandler {
    @Autowired
    RequestHolder requestHolder;

    @GetMapping("/setResult")
    public void setResult() {

        for (DeferredResult request: requestHolder.getRequestList()) {

            request.setResult("Hello World!");
        }
        requestHolder.clear();

    }

}
```

The issue I currently have is that the code where myVar should have its value will run before a value is set. Is there a way to make it so it will wait for the DeferredResult to have a value or is there a different method I should use to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a `DeferredResult`, perhaps `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture` would suit you. You could set the result on the future by using `complete` and you can wait for a result using `get` (optionally specifying a timeout).

One last thing: I assume that `requestList` in `RequestHolder` needs synchronization to be thread safe. The easiest thing would be `java.util.Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`.